# Google maps crashed when opening through my application

Tags: android, maps

I am developing an application which has functionality of locate us.

When user clicks on locate us button user will redirected to a particular location that i want to show on google maps.

This works fine, my application redirects to google maps application and it opens location which i want to show but when i click back button on maps it displays my welcome page and sometimes it shows me error that "Unfortunately maps stopped".

I tried everything but unable to find what is the issue. Can anyone please help me.

This is my Welcome.java Activity :

```java
package mainApplication;

import java.io.File;
import readFile.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Locale;

import logs.TraceLog;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import forbes.mPassbook.R;
public class Welcome extends Activity 
{
    ImageButton LoginHere,RegisterNow,Locate_us;
    String uri ="https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Bank+Of+Bahrain+And+Kuwait+BBK/@19.0822508,72.8812041,11z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1sbank+of+bahrain+in+mumbai!3m1!1s0x3be7d1e96fffffff:0x5e96526f98c8e98";

    String file_Path;

    TraceLog tc =new TraceLog();    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        ActionBar bar=getActionBar();
        bar.hide();

        file_Path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Android/data/forbes.mPassbook/";

        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        }

        File conf=new File(file_Path + "config.properties");
        if(!conf.exists()) 
        {
            copyFiles();
        }
        ReadConfig rc = new ReadConfig();


        /****************GIF code implementation***********************/
        /*ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
         img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gifanim);

         // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
         AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

         // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
         frameAnimation.start();*/

        LoginHere = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.image_user_login);
        RegisterNow = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.image_register);
        Locate_us =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.image_locateus);

        RegisterNow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Welcome.this, Registration.class);

                //              // Closing all the Activities
                //              i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                //
                //              // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                //              i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        LoginHere.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                File file_cust_id=new File(file_Path + "customer.properties");
                if(file_cust_id.exists())
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Welcome.this, Login.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Register First",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               
                }
            }
        });

        //Locate us button

        Locate_us.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                try
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                            Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Bank+Of+Bahrain+And+Kuwait+BBK,+Ground+Floor,+225,+Jolly+Maker+Chambers,/@18.925573,72.824222,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x3be7d1e96fffffff:0x5e96526f98c8e98?hl=en"));
                    startActivity(intent);

                    //                  Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                    //                  intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                    //                  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    //                  startActivity(intent);
                    //                  //                      finish();   
                }               
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error In Google Maps",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    //Copy Property Files from Asset Folder to SD card on startup
    public void copyFiles()
    {
        try 
        {
            File dataDirectory = new File(file_Path);
            // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
            if(!dataDirectory.exists())
                dataDirectory.mkdirs();

            AssetManager am = getAssets();
            String[] list = am.list("");
            for (String s:list) 
            {
                if (s.startsWith("config")) 
                {
                    InputStream inStream = am.open(s);
                    int size = inStream.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    inStream.read(buffer);
                    inStream.close();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file_Path + s);
                    fos.write(buffer);
                    fos.close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            tc.WriteToTransactionLog("Exception: Welcome.java copyFiles():- "+ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) 
        {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        try
        {
            //Success Register dialog box
            Exit e = new Exit(Welcome.this);
            e.show();
            e.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        finish();
    }

    //  public void onRestart() 
    //  {
    //      super.onRestart();
    //      startActivity(new Intent(this, Welcome.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    //  }
}
```

My Welcome.xml :

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="forbes.welcome.Hdfc_welcome" 
    android:background="@drawable/bbk_base_screen">

    -  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_user_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image_register"
        android:src="@drawable/user_login" /> 

    <ImageButton

        android:id="@+id/image_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/register" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/image_locateus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image_register"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/locate_us_icon" />

<!-- <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_hdfc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text_welcome"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_welcome"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="#d4ccb9"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:text="M-Passbook" /> -->

   <!--  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#d4ccb9"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_icon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_hdfc"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/user_name" >
       </EditText>  
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#d4ccb9"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/key_icon"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_user"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_login"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText_user"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText_password"
    android:src="@drawable/unlock_icon" />   -->

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text_welcome"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/image_user_login"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
     android:text="Welcome To mPassbook"
     android:textColor="#d4ccb9"
     android:textSize="24sp"
     android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My LogCat shows me this :

```
12-05 09:29:41.432: D/GraphicBuffer(11527): create handle(0x5e919910) (w:544, h:960, f:1)
12-05 09:29:41.436: D/GraphicBuffer(11527): close handle(0x5e919910) (w:544 h:960 f:1)
12-05 09:29:41.441: D/GraphicBuffer(11527): create handle(0x5e919910) (w:544, h:960, f:1)
12-05 09:29:41.494: D/OpenGLRenderer(11527): Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-05 09:29:50.212: V/InputMethodManager(11527): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=32 first=true flags=#1810100
12-05 09:29:50.213: V/InputMethodManager(11527): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41168cf0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-540,960} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@415c3e08 controlFlags=#104
12-05 09:29:50.215: V/InputMethodManager(11527): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@415c4698 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #7009}
12-05 09:29:50.239: D/GraphicBuffer(11527): create handle(0x5e0fe628) (w:544, h:960, f:1)
12-05 09:29:50.251: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11527): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5c9eaeb0) fps:0.11, dur:8780.78, max:8780.78, min:8780.78
12-05 09:29:50.251: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11527): [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x5c9eaeb0, api:1, last queue time elapsed:8780.78
```

Comment: Can you show what is the error you are getting ??

Comment: Yes
Plz add your Stack Trace or Logcat Report...........

Comment: this is the only thing that logcat displays there, unable to understand what exactly it is?